# How to get text written into html tag based on some class and id?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create an HTML page in which it should print item names (which is inside the div container) on the click of a button into a paragraph below and the condition is -
it should only print those items which are having class name as "active" and parent id as "selected".

I tried doing this, here is my code -

```js
function myFunction() {
    var selectedEl = document.querySelector(".selected");
    var items = selectedE1.getElementsByClassName('active');
    
    document.getElementById('listItems').innerHTML = items;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="example1 selected">
        <div class="item1"> ex1 item1 </div>
        <div class="item2 active"> ex1 item2 </div>
        <div class="item3"> ex1 item3 </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="example2">
        <div class="item1"> ex2 item1 </div>
        <div class="item2 active"> ex2 item2 </div>
        <div class="item3 active"> ex2 item3 </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="example3 selected">
        <div class="item1 active"> ex3 item1 </div>
        <div class="item2"> ex3 item2 </div>
        <div class="item3"> ex3 item3 </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="example4 selected">
        <div class="item1"> ex4 item1 </div>
        <div class="item2"> ex4 item2 </div>
        <div class="item3"> ex4 item3 </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br> <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Items</button>
<br><br>
<strong>Item List:<br></strong>
<p id="listItems"></p>
```

For the above code, the expected output should be -
**Item List:**
ex1 item2
ex3 item1

**Note:** You can use JavaScript and JQuery

Please help me doing this.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You are using `id` wrong. If you want multiple selectors you should use `class`

Answer (score 1):

The [*`id`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) selector value is not valid (***[*`id`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)'s value must not contain whitespace*** and ***must be unique in the whole document***). Using *class* attribute you can try the following way:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(".selected  > .active");
    var res="";
    //items.forEach(i => res += i.textContent + '<br/>'); // if you want to show in document
    items.forEach(i => res += i.textContent + '\n'); // if you want to show in alert
    //document.getElementById('listItems').innerHTML = res;
    alert(res)
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="example1 selected">
        <div class="item1"> ex1 item1 </div>
        <div class="item2 active"> ex1 item2 </div>
        <div class="item3"> ex1 item3 </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="example2">
        <div class="item1"> ex2 item1 </div>
        <div class="item2 active"> ex2 item2 </div>
        <div class="item3 active"> ex2 item3 </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="example3 selected">
        <div class="item1 active"> ex3 item1 </div>
        <div class="item2"> ex3 item2 </div>
        <div class="item3"> ex3 item3 </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="example4 selected">
        <div class="item1"> ex4 item1 </div>
        <div class="item2"> ex4 item2 </div>
        <div class="item3"> ex4 item3 </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br> <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Items</button>
<br><br>
<strong>Item List:<br></strong>
<p id="listItems"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! but what if I want to use id? Is there any way to do it by id only?

Comment: @AKSHITKAKANI1941007, as already mentioned the answer that *id must be unique in the whole document*, I think you can not achieve that in the way want:)

Comment: Imo it should be `id="example1" class="selected"` and so on. `example1`, `example2` etc are unique identifiers, also they aren't a good example of generic class for starters

Comment: But when I am printing the text in alert box using the same variable res, "alert(res)", it is giving me output as whole tag instead of that item names? What should I do in this case?

Comment: @AKSHITKAKANI1941007, you want show only the text then use `textContent`. updated the answer, please check:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate based on the class

Eg :

```
$('.selected .active').each(function(i, obj) {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: No, it didn't help me. Can you be more specific, please?